# incrontab IN_CREATE event fires four times

Tags: bash, incron

I was looking into [incrontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab) and tried it out as follows:

/tmp/incron.sh :

```
echo "$1 Content: `cat /tmp/test/a`" >> /tmp/incron.log
```

`incrontab -l`:

```
/tmp/test/a IN_CLOSE_WRITE /tmp/incron.sh write
/tmp/test/ IN_CREATE /tmp/incron.sh create
```

I created `/tmp/test/a` and after saving the file, this was in the log:

```
create Content: 
create Content: 
create Content: 
create Content: test
```

I think I understand why there is no `write Content:` entry in the log - as the file did not exist when the daemon loaded the table

After editing the file, This is what the log looked like:

```
create Content: 
create Content: 
create Content: 
create Content: test
create Content: test
create Content: test
create Content: test
create Content: test 2
create Content: test 2
```

I then restarted the daemon(`sudo service incron restart`) and edited the file again. Now this is what the log looked like:

```
create Content: 
create Content: 
create Content: 
create Content: test
create Content: test
create Content: test
create Content: test
create Content: test 2
create Content: test 2
create Content: test 2
create Content: test 2
create Content: test 2
create Content: test 3
create Content: test 3
write Content: test 3
```

Can someone please explain what is happening here?